# Difference between docker -d and doing ctrl-p+ctrl-q after launching interactively?

Tags: docker

Is `docker -d` more efficient than simply first running interactively with `docker -i -t` and then detaching with ctrl-p + ctrl-q?

On my production server, I need to change some config settings after running the container. I could commit those config changes and start a new container from this image, but I'd rather just keep it in the first container and detach. Any dangers to this approach?

Comment: What happens if you run both and then measure your efficiency? What's your result?

Comment: @kkuilla How would you measure something like that?

Comment: @Nick How would you know whether `docker -d` is more efficient than `docker -i -t`? Only the asker would know what is important. He/she have to decide for themselves what efficiency means and then measure that.

Answer (score 0):

Having all your configurations in the Dockerfile and running `docker -d` is more efficient. Even if it means creating multiple Dockerfiles with unique configurations for each container.

The downside with configuring the container then detaching each time is that, its the manual way of doing things, which defeats the purpose of the Dockerfile. Also, it will take more time to replicate your container on another environment.

You can also explore using [Docker Environment Variables](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env), or Reading a configuration file from a [Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) to make your setup more dynamic.

Comment: I think your are missing the explanation as to why `docker -d` is more efficient. Could you explain how and why you got to this conclusion, please?